# Laravel + Bootstrap collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

My header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script href="/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And my content :

```
<a href="#subskills" data-toggle="collapse"> Subskills </a>
<div id="subskills" class="collapse">

@include("includes.subskills")
</div> <!--- HIDDEN SUBSKILLS  END -->
```

Pressing Subskills adds #subskills to the url and nothing else changes

Looking for help,
Show

Comment: Are you sure the javascript files are loaded correctly? Because that's sounds like there's no collapse plugin attached to the link.

Comment: `data-toggle="collapse"` does not work like tabs do. You need to add a `data-target="#subskills"` to the anchor. But this will probably only work for collapsible navs.

Comment: @DavidDomain If you're using an anchor element and pass the target id in the `href` attribute it's a perfectly legitimate use, unless the [Twitter Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) is wrong. `data-target` is for use with elements other than links.

Comment: @Bogdan - You're right. The anchor should work without the `data-target`. My bad.

Comment: Still nothing... Have tried different .js files and loaded them in different orders.